# How can I auto shrink text to fit div width and height using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I load information from my database which I put inside of the green boxes (in image). If the text will not properly fit the green box div because it is too long, how can I resize the text using javascript? Also the text can be on multiple lines, not just on 1. I have seen many answers online but most mess up the positioning and size of my green box div. I should mention that if the text does properly fit in the div already, I do not want to shrink it. I want it to have its default size.

```
.shortDescriptionContainer
{
    width:322px;
    height:60px;
    font-size:3em;
    background-color:green;
    float:left;
    margin-left:15px;
    margin-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You say "the text can be on multiple lines". Is it forced by using some wrapping block elements or `br` elements in the markup, or do you have a single textnode only, which is allowed to wrap in the solution you need?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean. When I say the text can be on multiple lines, I mean it can be displayed on multiple lines. The text I get from the database is all just one text. I mean the text can wrap to the next line. I'm not just restricting it to be on one line in the div.

Comment: In my picture the text is on one line, but I am just stating that it is allowed to span over multiple lines.

Comment: I am not really familiar with jQuery yet :S

Comment: I have a solution for you if you can add the jquery tag to your question.

Comment: Ok sure thank you. Just did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one solution. It has two iterations to allow text to wrap and to prevent long words from overflowing...

I set `width` and `min-height` on the parent `div`, and wrap the text inside in a `span` tag. This allows the div to stretch vertically with the text. I check the height of the `div` and reduce the font size until the `div` reaches the `min-height` CSS value.

That solves the text height and wrapping. Next, we need to handle long overflowing words... For that, I check each `span` inside each `div` and shrink text of all `spans` within the `div` if any `span` is wider than the `div`. -.-

Using `while` loops in this way, I felt it necessary to include loop limiters that will change the `div` backgrounds to red if there is a problem.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/96tccod8/

```js
$(function() {
    $('.fit-text').each(function() {
        // Fit height
        var fitHeight = parseInt($(this).css('min-height'));
        if ($(this).height() > fitHeight) {
            var c = 0;
            while ($(this).height() > fitHeight) {
                $(this).find('span').each(function() {
                    var fontSize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
                    fontSize = fontSize - 1 + "px";
                    $(this).css('font-size', fontSize);
                });
                c++;
                if (c > 999) {
                    $(this).css('background', 'red');
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        // Fit width
        var fitWidth = parseInt($(this).css('width'));
        var $div = $(this);
        $(this).find('span').each(function() {
            var c = 0;
            var spanWidth = parseInt($(this).width());
            while (fitWidth < spanWidth) {
                $div.find('span').each(function() {
                    var fontSize = parseInt($(this).css('font-size'));
                    fontSize = fontSize - 1 + "px";
                    $(this).css('font-size', fontSize);
                });
                spanWidth = parseInt($(this).width());
                c++;
                if (c > 999) {
                    $div.css('background', 'red');
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.fit-text {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    /* width and min-height values are important */
    width: 240px;
    min-height: 50px;
    background: darkgreen;
    margin: 10px;
}

.fit-text span {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="fit-text">
    <span>TEST</span>
</div>

<div class="fit-text">
    <span>SUPERMEGAMANXZERO</span>
</div>

<div class="fit-text">
    <span>TEST TEST </span>
    <span>SECONDSPANLONGWORD</span>
</div>

<div class="fit-text">
    <span>TEST TEST TEST</span>
</div>

<div class="fit-text">
    <span>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</span>
</div>

<div class="fit-text">
    <span>TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Added width checking as well.

Comment: Nice solution, but I could not able to understand how does it work without counting the string length ?

Comment: Because I'm simply measuring the div size. The text inside will stretch it bigger, and I reduce the text size until the div shrinks to the desired size.

Comment: I am just looking into jQuery before I implement this. I will accept your answer when I implement it to see :)

Comment: I noticed that after adding width handling for long words, the text no longer wrapped... So, the post has been updated with the third version that supports both wrapping text and long overflowing words. It's a bit longer, but seems to do the trick.

Comment: I got it to work but I noticed that if I refresh the page it shows the text before it is resized for a few seconds before it finally resizes it to how I want it. This probably doesn't have anything to do with your answer, but is there something I can do to not show my information before it is resized properly? It isn't that visually appealing to see it all unformatted before it is resized :P

Comment: Sure. The usual `display: none`, then `show()` when it's done doesn't work in this case. Here's an example solution using CSS `opacity`. In the CSS, I set `opacity: 0`, then when the fit-text JS stuff is done running, I set the `opacity` to 1. https://jsfiddle.net/shphm8k1/